# Remove 2 characters in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a column that contains 12 digits but user wants only to generate a 10 digits.

I tried the trim, ltrim function but nothing work. Below are the queries I tried.

```
ltrim('10', 'column_name')
ltrim('10', column_name)
ltrim(10, column_name)
```

For example I have a column that contains a 12 digit number

```
100000000123
100000000456
100000000789
```

and the expected result I want is

```
0000000123
0000000456
0000000789
```

Comment: try the substring method https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php

Comment: WHICH ten digits do you need to retrieve? Always the LAST ten digits of the number? Also, is the number always EXACTLY 12 digits? (And, note that you are not talking about NUMBERS at all, you are talking about **STRINGS**. As numbers, 000000000789 is the same as 789.)

Comment: One more thing... is it ever possible that `column_name` has **less** than 10 digits to begin with? Then what should be the output?

Comment: Why your approach didn't work: `LTRIM` does not remove a substring from the left side of a string. It always removes *individual characters*. In your case it will remove as many 0's and 1's as it can find at the beginning (left end) of the string, and it will only stop trimming when it finds a character that is neither 0 nor 1. It will not remove the **substring** (of length two) '10'.

Comment: Hi @mathguy the last ten digits is I need to retrieve like in the example. The item in the column_name is always 12 digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract the last 10 characters of an input string, regardless of how long the string is (so this will work if some inputs have 10 characters, some 12, and some 15 characters), you could use negative starting position in `substr`:

```
substr(column_name, -10)
```

For example:

```
with
  my_table(column_name) as (
    select '0123401234'    from dual union all
    select '0001112223334' from dual union all
    select '12345'         from dual union all
    select '012345012345'  from dual
  )
select column_name, substr(column_name, -10) as substr
from   my_table;

COLUMN_NAME   SUBSTR    
------------- ----------
0123401234    0123401234
0001112223334 1112223334
12345                   
012345012345  2345012345
```

Note in particular the third example. The input has only 5 digits, so obviously you can't get a 10 digit number from it. The result is NULL (undefined).

Note also that if you use something like `substr(column_name, 3)` you will get just `'345'` in that case; most likely not the desired result.

Comment: For the case that you expose, and to get a solution working always, you can preempt the column name with ten zeros, and then apply the substring function (or if null, set the column name directly)

Comment: @JaimeDrq That is one possibility. However, a programmer should never make such decisions on their own. Rather, the question must be posed to the business users who asked for this solution - what do **they** need? Too many programmers will simply do something like what you suggested so that they can "move on" to the next problem, with no thought given to what the business user may need in such cases that weren't covered by the initial problem statement.

Answer (score -1):

try to use    `SUBSTR(column_name, 2)`

Comment: Do you mean 3, not 2, as the starting position?